# Black hole information paradox

Tags: thermodynamics, black-holes, event-horizon, information, qft-in-curved-spacetime

I read that it is generally believed that information is preserved in black hole evaporation, and people's views only diverge when it comes to *how* information is preserved. Is this true?

Comment: Some PBS Space Time videos may help. Start with [Why Quantum Information is Never Destroyed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HF-9Dy6iB_4)

Comment: Then watch [The Black Hole Information Paradox](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9XkHBmE-N34)

Comment: Then [Have We SOLVED The Black Hole Information Paradox with Wormholes?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=epSev7ovVew)

Comment: It is not a consensus that information is preserved. Important relativists such as [Unruh and Wald](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.02140) believe there is no "paradox" at all in information loss, although this is often overlooked in science communication

Answer (score 2):

This is not true. There is *not* a consensus that information is preserved. There are important relativists, such as [Unruh and Wald](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.02140) that argue there is nothing paradoxical about information loss in black hole evaporation. For these physicists, it could happen that information is conserved, but this is not a necessity.

For disclosure, I do not believe there is anything wrong with information loss. The black hole evaporation spacetime obtained in Hawking's original calculation (and considered to hold until the evaporation ends) is not globally hyperbolic (meaning even *classical* initial value problems are ill-defined) and there is no reason to expect information to be conserved in such a scenario. The paper by Unruh and Wald I linked above has an excellent discussion of this point of view.

Comment: @A.V.S. I edited the answer

Comment: Ignoring the information paradox is impossible once you understand its physical meaning. As observed from outside, an astrophysical black hole contains everything that has ever fallen located just above the horizon. In any coordinates, the black hole evaporates before anything crosses the horizon. Thus everything must remain and nothing should disappear, but all mass already has evaporated. The root of the paradox is that a black hole is made of the matter that is not a part of the black hole. Matter cannot evaporate and not evaporate at the same time with both results observed from outside.

Comment: To clarify, the paradox is caused by extending the GR validity too close to the absolute horizon. However, if you admit that something (like a firewall or another singularity) destroys matter just above the horizon, e.g. at the stretched horizon (a spacelike surface a Planck length above the absolute null horizon that never forms anyway), then there is no paradox. If geodesics end in a timelike singularity just above the horizon, then there is no further evolution of matter and thus no paradox. The use case in my previous comment is also resolved.